# Syllables in "trickling"?

Tags: syllables

Could someone please explain why almost every website says "trickling" has two syllables? Is tri-kel-ing a regional dialect? Is it two syllables when being written?

Comment: That's so strange, I have *always* said and heard that word with 3 syllables, but can't find a single search result to back that up now. Looking at the descriptions given on some of the "how many syllables" type sites, it seems like they commonly use an algorithm to calculate number-of-syllables for a word. It is *possible* that this algorithm is getting tripped up by the fact that the middle syllable (of 3) is actually *syllabic **l***, which is a consonant that stands on its own with no vowel.

Comment: A relevant quote from this site: https://sarahsnippets.com/syllable-division-rules/ : "The first thing to know is that every syllable must have a **written** vowel" (emphasis added).  But, to syllabify "trickling" as [trick l ing] does not follow that rule.

Comment: This dictionary **does** list the 3-syllable pronunciation as a variant (it transcribes it with an optional shwa sound instead of showing the syllabic "l"): https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trickle

Comment: By the way, this is a great first question! Welcome to EL&U :)

Comment: Where did you see it with 2 syllables? Were any in reliable, edited, sources from reputable publishers? Please provide references. (Don't trust what random strangers on the internet say; it's likely to be an oversimplification if it's not wrong.)

Comment: **syncopation** is not uncommon.  In mid-Atlantic AmE, you hear both pronunciations.   You can't rely on spelling.  Spelling is no more than an approximate representation, and  "eing" would be weird, given the history of spelling reform.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/trickle) doesn't have IPA for *trickling*, only for *trickle*, but it does have audio that agrees with your (presumably, accents aside) and my pronunciation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two pronunciations of this word are contained in the following LPD's phonetic notation (*Longman Pronunciation Dictionary*).

> \ˈtrɪk ᵊl‿ɪŋ\

1. \ˈtrɪk ᵊl ɪŋ\: 3 phonetic syllables — This is the uncompressed pronunciation (for example, when pronouncing the word  in isolation).
2. \ˈtrɪk lɪŋ\: 2 phonetic syllables — This pronunciation is the usual one (compressed).

LPD provides a guide on the use of these two pronunciations.

> (**LPD**,  p. 173) Generally the uncompressed version is more usual
>
> - in rarer words
> - in slow or deliberate speech¹
> - the first time a word is used in a given discourse
>
> The compressed version is more usual
>
> - in frequently  used words¹
> - in fast or casual speech¹
> - if the word has already been used in the discourse

¹<sub>**user LPH's note**: applies in the case of "trickling"</sub>